# Connect 2 computer via lan to view website

Tags: iis-7, lan

Here is the deal:
I have 2 computers connected via switch.
Both computers can see(ping) each other.
One of the computers (computer A) is running IIS7. And hosts a website on port 80.
So from computer A you can access website by typing in browser 
 http://localhost:80/website/Default.aspx.
Computer A' IP 192.168.0.2

The question is how to configure IIS to allow other computers on network see the website.

If I just type in browser on computer B http://192.168.0.2:80/website/Default.aspx it would not find anything.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the windows firewall is enabled on the web server machine.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a firewall issue, port 80 is probably closed on the server, once you turn off the firewall, it should start working, then you can add an exception to the firewall for port 80 and turn it back on.

Comment: Allow your IIS on port 80, 8080 as well